# Selenium IE Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am working on Selenium java scripts, using IE webdriver script I can identify an element but `.click()` is not working. Is there any other way to press ENTER against that webelement. After clicking this element one drop down appears; I want to select one element from that drop down. 
Help is appreciated.

```
WebElement sve = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='rptReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button']"));

if( sve.isDisplayed()){
    sve.click();
    System.out.println("element found");
} else {
    System.out.println("element not found");
}
```

below is the button ids; 
    
    font-size: 10pt; border: 1px solid rgb(51, 102, 153); background-color: 
    rgb(221, 238, 247); cursor: pointer;">

```
<table id="rptReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button" border="0"   

title="Export drop down menu">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a id="rptReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonLink" style="text-decoration:   
none; cursor: pointer;" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="Export drop down  
menu" title="Export drop down menu">

<img id="rptReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImg" style="border-
style:None;height:16px;width:16px;border-width:0px;" alt="Export drop down  
menu" src="/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?

OpType=Resource&Version=11.0.2802.16&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.Export.gif"/>

<span style="width:5px;text-decoration:none;"/>
<img id="rptReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImgDown" style="border- 
style:None;height:6px;width:7px;border-width:0px;margin-bottom:5px;"    
alt="Export drop down menu" src="/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?  
 OpType=Resource&Version=11.0.2802.16&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.ArrowDown.gif"/>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's been 3 years since I worked with Selenium WebDriver, but if I remember, I usually had to add a waitAndClick command (don't know if that's the exact command) before it would find the element.  Many times, you get redirected to a new page, and the page didn't render yet.  Or you're trying to click a popup, and the command runs before the popup is rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am getting "element found" output.

Comment: Can you define **click() is not working** There are so many strategies to select element from a dropdown. What you are trying to accomplish specifically?

Comment: i have given html details for button I am trying to click. Once clicked it gives one list; I want to select one item from that list.